# Using a polymorphic relation to represent all pages on my website

Tags: php, laravel, database-design, model, relationship

I'm currenlty learning how to use Laravel by designing a Blog like website.
I would like to use a polymorphic relationship to represent all page of the site then having a subtable "posts" containing all posts related data.

This is a picture representing my current database design (I have simplified the attributes)

[image: database diagram]

I'm not sure that it's the best approach to handle my data
Can you give me some advices to improve my ideas ?

I have implemented my current database design but find it hard to update the post related page

Comment: I think you should have a `page_types` table that has polymorphic relationship with posts,pages,articles and whatever you prefer.... Anyway IMO it can be done with a simple `page_type_id` attribute.... so a `BelongsTo` relationship from posts, pages and so on to the page type

Comment: Thanks for you advice. I had the feeling that I wasn't using the best option. I will implement your ideas right away !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following IGala answer, having a type field is the correct way to handle inheritance in SQL.